# Dynamic Multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, matrix-multiplication, dynamic-arrays

I made Matrix Multiplication program in c++ using dynamic Multidimensional arrays. 
problem is when i enter test values 
matrix A = row1{ 1 }  ,  row2 { 2 }  matrix B = row1 {1 ,2 , 3}  , it stops working at the loop where user 
inputs values of first array , i found it using debugging. but program works fine when i enter
matrix A = row1{ 1 , 2  }  ,  row2 { 3 , 4  }  matrix B = row1 {5 , 6 } , row2 {7 , 8}

i want this program to be a general program that can multiply all matrixs

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Lab_02
{
public:
    void Product(){
    int a1Rows, a1Columns;
    int a2Rows, a2Columns;
    cout << "Plz Enter the no. of rows for Array 1      :";
    cin >> a1Rows;

    cout << "Plz Enter the no. of columns for Array 1   :";
    cin >> a1Columns;

    cout << "Plz Enter the no. of rows for Array 2      :";
    cin >> a2Rows;

    cout << "Plz Enter the no. of columns for Array 2   :";
    cin >> a2Columns;

    int **dynamicArray = 0;
    int **dynamicArray2 = 0;
    int **dynamicArray3 = 0;
    cout << endl;


    for (int i = 0; i < a1Rows; i++)
    {
        dynamicArray3 = new int *[a1Rows];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a2Columns; i++)
    {
        dynamicArray3[i] = new int[a2Columns];
    }



    // memory allocated for elements of rows. 
    for (int i = 0; i < a1Rows; i++)
    {
        dynamicArray = new int *[a1Rows];
    }
    // memory allocated for  elements of each column.  
    for (int i = 0; i < a1Columns; i++)
    {
        dynamicArray[i] = new int[a1Columns];
    }


    // memory allocated for elements of rows. 
    for (int i = 0; i < a2Rows; i++)
    {
        dynamicArray2 = new int *[a2Rows];
    }
    // memory allocated for  elements of each column.  
    for (int i = 0; i < a2Columns; i++)
    {
        dynamicArray2[i] = new int[a2Columns];
    }


    cout << "enter the values or array 1 \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < a1Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a1Columns; j++)
        {
            cout << "array[" << i << "][" << j << "]\t";
            cin >> dynamicArray[i][j];

        }

    }

    cout << "enter the values or array 2 :\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < a2Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a2Columns; j++)
        {
            cout << "array[" << i << "][" << j << "]\t"; 
            cin >> dynamicArray2[i][j];

        }
    }


    int sum; 


    for (int i = 0; i < a1Rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a1Columns ; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k <  a2Columns ; k++)
            {
                sum = sum + (dynamicArray[i][k] * dynamicArray2[k][j]);
            }
            dynamicArray3[i][j] = sum;
        }

    }


        cout <<"Result" << endl << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < a1Rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a2Columns; j++)
            {
                cout << dynamicArray3[i][j] << "\t";

            }
            cout << endl;
        }


    }
   };


        void main(void)
        {

         Lab_02 object;   
           object.Product();

          }
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `std::vector` and rid yourself of these issues?

Comment: Because I am bound to do it this way ! , beside if its possible then why not , i'll study the better ways later , first i have to go through each concept :)

Comment: I don't understand your description of what you inputted.  How many rows and columns did you enter for Array1, how many rows/columns did you enter for Array2?

Comment: thanks for understanding :) !  for Array 1 , 2 row and 1 Columns

Comment: For Array 2 , 
1 row and 3 columns

Comment: Arrays don't forget their data; they're not *dementional*.

Answer (score 0):

Your memory allocations for the matricies are the issue.
Change them to something like the following

```
// memory allocated for elements of rows. 
dynamicArray = new int *[a1Rows];

// memory allocated for  elements of each column.  
for (int i = 0; i < a1Rows; i++)
{
    dynamicArray[i] = new int[a1Columns];
}
```

You need to allocate one array of array for the rows and then you need to loop over the rows and allocate the columns.

Comment: this is exactly what i am doing :( 
you can see my and your code . they are exactly the same

Comment: No, you are allocating rows in a loop and then loop over the number of columns to allocate the columns

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code is that you are not supposed to allocate the "rows" in a loop.  All you need is one allocation for the rows, and then loop to allocate the data for each row.

So for example, instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a1Rows; i++)
{
    dynamicArray = new int *[a1Rows];
}
// memory allocated for  elements of each column.  
for (int i = 0; i < a1Columns; i++)
{
    dynamicArray[i] = new int[a1Columns];
}
```

The correct way would be this:

```
dynamicArray = new int *[a1Rows];
for (int i = 0; i < a1Columns; i++)
{
    dynamicArray[i] = new int[a1Columns];
}
```

You made the same mistake for each of the loops.

Also, some points:

1. You failed to deallocate the memory that was allocated.
2. If you used `std::vector`, then things become much easier.
3. You need to check if the matrices are multiplyable before performing the `sum` loop.  By `multiplyable` meaning that the number of columns and rows of matrix A and B satisfy the requirements for multiplication of A and B.

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < a1Rows; i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < a1Columns; j++)
       {
           sum = 0;
           for (int k = 0; k < a2Columns; k++)
               sum = sum + (dynamicArray[i][k] * dynamicArray2[k][j]);
           dynamicArray3[i][j] = sum;
       }
   }
   ```

This loop will go haywire if the `dynamicArray1` and `dynamicArray2` do not have the requisite number of columns and rows before multiplying.

First, the following test should be done before multiplying:

```
if (a1Columns != a2Rows)
    return;
```

Second, your `k` loop is wrong.  It should be this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < a2Rows; k++)
    sum = sum + (dynamicArray[i][k] * dynamicArray2[k][j]);
dynamicArray3[i][j] = sum;
```

Comment: hey PaulMcKenz , 
i agree with all 3 points of yours :) 
the reason i am using loop for memory allocation of rows is because i want this program to be general program that can multiply all multiply-able matrix's

Comment: What if i have a Matrix that has more then 1 number of rows , getting my point ?